# What are the differential voltage technology used for PCIe gen 4, gen 5 and gen 6?

Tags: transmission-line, pcie, lvds, data-rate

I have been studying various IO standards used for various PCIe generations? I understand that PCIe Gen-3 uses LVDS, LVPECL and PCML.

I would like to learn what are the standards used for other generations.

Q1) From, [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snla187/snla187.pdf?ts=1615400787374&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) application note, LVDS is limited unto 3.125 Gbps. So, what if the PCIe requirement is more than 3.125 Gbps?

Q2) How the maximum data-rate is determined?

[image]

Comment: Are gen 5 and 6 even implemented yet?

Comment: I have not seen any product with gen 5 and 6, but I am wondering if the specification is finalized